# Apply a style to TextBlocks within a ContentPresenter in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, styles, textblock, contentpresenter

If I have the following style defined:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="ProblemStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then when I have a ContentPresenter data bound to a string, in WPF I can get it to style the text as required with the following XAML:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Problem}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource ProblemStyle}" />
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

However, in Silverlight, this doesn't work. Is there a way that works for both?

Comment: I don't understand. Why not just have a `TextBlock` bound to the string?

Comment: This is a minimal example that reproduces the problem.  It's easy to envision a much more complicated example that couldn't be trivially replaced with a bound `TextBlock`.

Comment: @Kent - because "Problem" is not necessarily a string. I've updated my ViewModel now so that "Problem" is itself a TextBlock

Answer (score 6):

Use the  TextElement Attached property. You will not be able to set a style, but most of the properties that effects the Textblock are there..

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              TextElement.FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                              TextElement.FontSize="12"
                              TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"
                              TextElement.Foreground="White"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
```

Comment: this only works in wpf

Answer (score 0):

First: 
Make sure that your style "ProblemStyle" is being loaded before the application tries to render the ContentPresenter. In Silverlight, the order the styles are defined makes a difference, and if it has not been loaded first then it may not be reading anything.

Ok, I am going to run on some assumptions here, the first one being that you are using a ContentControl to display something and that the ContentPresenter is inside of this control.

But why not create a Style for the ContentControl?

```
<Style x:key="ProblemStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
  <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
```

Then your ContentControl would have the Style set to the StaticResource of "ProblemStyle".

Since by default the template of a ContentControl has the ContentPresenter - or you can define the ContentPresenter template in the style as well:

```
<Style x:key="ProblemStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
  <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
          <Border>
             <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
          </Border>
       </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

The template there is just as a placeholder to give an idea of where it would/could be located.

Comment: Some properties of the TextBlock can't be set in ContentControl style, for ex. TextWrapping